# "Crossed" sums between two vectors

Tags: clojure

I have two vectors (or collections, nevermind) like that : 
[1 2 3...

Let's say

```
(def v (range 1 4))
```

I would like to compute a "crossed"-sum of this vector.
I mean for each x in v, compute it's sum with every values of v.

Imagine the vector is [1 2 3], I want a matrix like that :

```
    (1)(2)(3)
(1)  2  3  4
(2)  3  4  5
(3)  4  5  6
```

I don't know if I'm clear but I do not see any Clojure function to do it.
I would think about a recursion or permuttations but it do not seem very idiomatic.

Any idea ?

Thanks !

**EDIT**

Code example to compute the "crossed" sum (only if numbers are distinct), reduce the sum at mod n and then computing stats about it

```
(defn crossed-sum [n]
  (let [v (range 1 (+ n 1))]
    (mapcat
      (fn [x]
        (for [k v
              :let [y (cond (= k x)
                              -1
                            :else
                              (+ k x))]]
          y))
      v)))

(defn mod-reduc [data n]
  (map
    (fn [x]
      (rem x n))
    data))


(defn compute-probability [n]
  (let [c-sum (-> (crossed-sum n)
                  (mod-reduc n)
                  (frequencies)
                  (dissoc -1))
        s (reduce + (vals c-sum))]
    (apply conj (map
                  (fn [[k v]]
                    {k (float (/ v s))})
                 c-sum))))
```

I used `for` but is it idiomatic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTW, `range` returns lazy seq, not a vector. But, it's not important here.

Just enough using `for`.

```
(let [numbers (range 1 4)]
  (for [n numbers
        m numbers]
    (+ n m)))
;; -> (2 3 4 3 4 5 4 5 6)
```

If you want to calculate only distinct numbers, you can write like this.

```
(let [numbers (range 1 4)]
  (for [n numbers
        m numbers
        :when (not= n m)]
    (+ n m)))
;; -> (3 4 3 5 4 5)
```

Comment: Did not really know what answer to accept since both have an input but here I learned the :when condition, far better than cond for readability. For the list of list, I can use map instead of mapcat. Yes vectors are not mandatory, I speak like that because I'm more into mathematical language

Answer (score 2):

This function produces a list of lists (in place of a matrix) just like what you have described in your example.

```
(defn cross-add [v]
    (for [number v]
      (map #(+ number %)
           v)))
```

Examples:

```
user> (cross-add [1 2 3])
((2 3 4) (3 4 5) (4 5 6))

user> (cross-add [5 13 8 9 12])
((10 18 13 14 17) (18 26 21 22 25) (13 21 16 17 20) (14 22 17 18 21) (17 25 20 21 24))
```

Comment: Thanks too, I forgot I asked for a list of list ! I can use ma instead of mapcat